# Version Update of APK

Tags: android

I have prepared an Apk for a customer and on his website I will have a link for download of the apk via google playstore.
Later I will be updating the Apk and uploading fresh one on Goolge Playstore.

How will the end users apk get updated ?
Does Google Playstore give any such provision I could use ?

I am using Delphi 10

Comment: If the user downloaded from the Google Play Store, any updates that you push to the Play Store will allow the user to update the app.

Comment: Do I have to make any provision in my current APK for this purpose ?